# NSOperationQueue Downloading Webpages Asynchronously

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have a program where I currently download 3 different URL's in a straight line and I want to modify it so I can download the webpages asynchronously, but I want all 3 the webpage downloads to be completed before the program progresses. I have seen tutorials online but I still havent been able to get NSOperation and NSoperationqueue to work.

This the NSOperation Class I created

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface LoadPage : NSOperation

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSURL *URL;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSData *webpage;

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url;
- (void)main;

@end
```

It is simply designed to download a webpage

```
#import "LoadPage.h"
//Loadpage.m
@implementation LoadPage
@synthesize URL;
@synthesize webpage;

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url{
    [self setURL:url];
    return self;
}
//Download Webpage function
- (void)main {
    NSData *page = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    [self setWebpage:page];
}
```

I want to download 3 separate webpages and have all those 3 webpages completed simultaneously and after they are all finished move on to executing the rest of the program.

```
@interface MasterParser : NSObject{
    NSOperationQueue *queue;
}

-(NSMutableArray *)loadPlayer:(NSString *)name;

@end

@implementation MasterParser
    -(NSMutableArray *)parsePage:(NSString *)name{
        NSURL *google = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.Google.com"];
        NSURL *yahoo = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"];
        NSURL *mlbtraderumors = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mlbtraderumors.com"];

        LoadPage *gpage = [[LoadPage alloc] initWithURL:google];
        LoadPage *ypage = [[LoadPage alloc] initWithURL:yahoo];
        LoadPage *mpage = [[LoadPage alloc] initWithURL:mlbtraderumors];

        queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [queue addOperation:gpage]; 
        [queue addOperation:ypage];
        [queue addOperation:mpage];

        [queue waitUnitilAllOperationsAreFinished];

        NSData *webpage = [gpage webpage];
    //...etc do all the operations and parsing with the webpages after all the downloads are done
}
```

When I run this the program freezes and I get a bad execution error. My suspicion is that I need to use a line at the end of my loadpage.m

```
    [MasterParser performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(parsePage:)
                                       withObject:nil
                                    waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: How is `-parsePage:` called? If your program freezes, that indicates to me that it's being executed on the main thread; That's probably not what you want. In general, this pattern may be easier to implement with GCD and blocks.

Comment: -pageParse: is called by another class which responds to a button press. I was wrong about the application freezing what actually happens is there is an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception on thread one 1.

The reason why I chose NSOperation over GCD is because I somewhat understood NSOp tutorials where I did not understand GCD at all.

Comment: If its happening in response to a button press, it's happening on the main thread. If you feel like NSOperationQueue is your weapon of choice, make another one of those and ship the call to -parsePage: off to that queue, and then let it ship the individual page loads off to another queue.

Comment: So your saying make another NSOperationQueue in the class that calls page parse and pass that queue off to pageParse where there in pageParse i load up the que of loadPage objects.

Comment: So I've Made some changes and the freezing has stopped. In loadpage.m's `- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url` method I added the line `    self = [super init]` and that has stopped the freezing and the program does run normally but the line in loadpage.m's main method `NSData *page = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL]` still when I try to access the NSData webpage objects in parsePage the webpages dont appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would like to thank everyone who has helped me answer this question. The key was adding the line

```
self=[super init];
to the initWithURL method after that everything started working.


#import "LoadPage.h"

@implementation LoadPage
@synthesize URL;
@synthesize webpage;


- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url{
    self = [super init];
    [self setURL:url];
    return self;
}
- (void)main {
    NSData *page = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    [self setWebpage:page];
}


@end
```

Thanks again to everyone who helped respond to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing itself shouldn't be much of a problem compared to downloading webpages, so it shouldn't create too much lag if you executed it on the main thread, but you can parse the webpages on the separate threads if you would like to.  Another thing I would like to point out is that if you are going to call `[MasterParser performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(parsePage:)
                                       withObject:nil
                                    waitUntilDone:YES];`, this will in turn call `+[MasterParser parsePage:nil]` on the main thread.  Instead it should be `self` (or whatever object calls that method), so `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(parsePage:)
                                       withObject:nil
                                    waitUntilDone:YES];`

Comment: `+[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` works with more than just local files. It definitely works with the HTTP URLs in the question.

Comment: @KurtRevis I apologize for that.  Should've done some research before I posted an answer.

Comment: Yea parsing isn't really the problem downloading the webpages is the thing I want to use the threading for. SO I have a question if I call `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(parsePage:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];` That will call the parsePage method but will each operation call parsePage? Because I would like it for all the operations to complete then the parsePage operation to move on and operate linearly. Thanks for the help.